# Can we reopen the Trump Tower wiretapping question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked [Did Obama's administration bug Trump Tower?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37475/did-obamas-administration-bug-trump-tower), and it was immediately put on hold because there was allegedly an ongoing investigation by "a court of law, government, or other similar investigative body."  The FBI has now [confirmed](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/04/opinion/trump-truth-wiretapping-obama.html) in a [court filing](https://assets.documentcloud.org/documents/3985960/DOJ-Motion-for-Summary-Judgment-in-Trump-Tower.pdf) that they have no record of any such investigation, ongoing or otherwise.  I am not aware of any other "court of law, government, or other similar investigative body" which is or was investigating the matter.  To my knowledge no one has presented any evidence that any such investigation or investigations exist, or have ever existed.

1. Should the question remain closed?
2. If so, under what circumstances will it be reopened?
3. Is it proper to close a question as "under investigation" when there is no evidence that anyone is actually investigating it?

Comment: Some are saying it should be closed now as the recent evidence shows there is an ongoing investigation on someone and that there are wire taps... I think it should stay open as this should be a site for asking about wire taps, black helicopters, Bigfoot sightings and those sorts of things that might always be involved in some form of investigation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No. I think that should be enough to re-open it.

We want to avoid falling over ourselves trying to answer questions based on evidence that is still filing in. We aren't journalists chasing down the breaking news. Sometimes our best response is to sit back and let the evidence arrive before we try to interpret it.

2) Generally, I would suggest a flag is sufficient. It only needs to come to meta, and get wider eyeballs if you disagree with the mod's response to the flag.

3) You have provided evidence that there was no FBI investigation. However, there was evidence at the time of other investigations:

- [CNN - same day the question was opened](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/03/05/politics/white-house-spicer-congress-2016/index.html):

  > Rep. Devin Nunes of California, the Republican chairman of the House Intelligence Committee, said his committee would look into whether the federal government was conducting wiretapping of campaign officials as part of the panel's investigation into Russian meddling in the US election.
  >
  > "One of the focus points of the House Intelligence Committee's investigation is the U.S. government's response to actions taken by Russian intelligence agents during the presidential campaign," Nunes said in a statement Sunday. "As such, the Committee will make inquiries into whether the government was conducting surveillance activities on any political party's campaign officials or surrogates, and we will continue to investigate this issue if the evidence warrants it."

Comment: @Kevin: Sorry, I think you are right. It isn't a direct answer. I was answering "What would trigger a reconsideration of whether it should be opened?" A: Flag is fine. Meta is typically overkill. I think you were asking "If a reconsideration is considered, what are the factors that affect tjay decision?" I don't have a straight answer to that. What do you think our policy should be?